# How can this sql query be injected?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I've a php code where I get the page number from a GET request and then run a sql query to select records from the database by the page number

```
$maxPerPage = 20;

$page = $_GET["p"];

$applicants = DB::query('SELECT * FROM registrees ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 
'.$page*$maxPerPage.','.$maxPerPage);
```

My question is can someone inject an SQL query in this code ? and if it could happen, I need examples of the sql-injection that can run here.

The problem here that the `$page` is multiplied with `$maxPerPage` if I tried to add any string in `$page` php will throw this error `A non-numeric value encountered`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: The answer looks obvious enough that I assume this is a homework problem.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not there is an injection point, why *wouldn't* you use prepared queries? You are basically asking "do I have to do this the safe way?" Never ask that question. Always default to the safe way and then only change tactics when absolutely necessary and you have clearly proven it safe. Also, in the meantime, why not convert `$page` to an int?

Comment: Also, letting your system generate an error when presented with unexpected input is not a reasonable choice under any circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in its current status is not running if `$page` is a string, so if you can't parse unexpected data, then it's not injectable. Even encoded commands would require the ability to parse more than just numerical data.